# node-oidc-provider missing offline_access scope

Tags: openid-connect, node-oidc-provider

I'm using node-oidc-provider v6 and missing offline_access scope in authorization response.
I found in the library code that offline_access can be automatically removed in some cases.
https://github.com/panva/node-oidc-provider/blob/v6.x/lib/actions/authorization/check_scope.js#L55

If I remove this line (line #55) everything works okay.
How can I add consent to prompts?

I have endpoint to handle prompt with consent screen.

```
case 'consent': {
        const consent = {
          rejectedScopes: [],
          rejectedClaims: [],
          replace: false,
        };

        return oidc.interactionFinished(
          req,
          res,
          { consent },
          {
            mergeWithLastSubmission: true,
          }
        );
      }
```

Comment: I have the exact same issue, please LMK if you managed to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're passing `prompt=consent` URL param to the initial code request (to the `/auth` endpoint).

More info: https://developers.google.com/identity/openid-connect/openid-connect#authenticationuriparameters

I also compared your code to mine and I'm pretty much using code from the Koa example. During the first OAuth request, `consent` is just an empty object. See [this example](https://github.com/panva/node-oidc-provider/blob/main/example/routes/koa.js#L192-L201) for reference